# Primes in solutions to Pell-type equations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pell-type-equations

What is known about primes in solutions to Pell-type equations?

In particular, consider the negative Pell equation $x^2 - 5 y^2 = -1$.
As far as I've been able to check
(in the first $4000$ solutions) the only positive-integer solution with $y$ prime  is $x=38$, $y=17$,
but I don't see any obvious reason why this should be the case.

Comment: Good question $(+1)$.  It seems every third $y$ is divisible by $17$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, if $a + b\sqrt{D} = (u + v\sqrt{D})^m$, then $v \mid b$. So only prime-index solutions (and the fundamental solution) can have $y$ prime. However, there are far more than one odd primes $\leqslant 4000$, so it's still remarkably rare. /// Robert, have you checked whether it's similarly rare for other $D$, e.g. $D \in \{13,17,29,37\}$, and for $x^2 - Dy^2 = +1$?

Comment: @DanielFischer there are some papers on primes or squares in linear second order recurrences such as Fibonacci. If the Pell target constant is $\pm 1$ this covers all solutions. The one I remember is Cohn on squares in Fibonacci, largest being 144; I see, primes are a very different matter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_prime

Comment: @DanielFischer:  is your response to me relevant to $x^2-5y^2=-1$ or just $x^2-5y^2=+1$?

Comment: @WillJagy Sounds like you might be in a position to answer with some references soon. (At least, you seem to have an idea where to look.)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner It's generally for $x^2 - Dy^2 = \pm 1$. For $x^2 - Dy^2 = -1$, $m$ must be odd of course.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A083103    so next we want such sequences with very few primes, and allowing coefficients in $x_{n+2} = A x_{n+1} + B x_n,$  allowing negative $B$ sometimes

Comment: @DanielFischer: For $D=13$, all solutions have $y$ divisible by $5$.  For $D = 17$, I think there are only four solutions with $y$ prime: $y = 4289, 283009, 1232221121, 389654665783729641056665815010661476514945825590106469015551207356585080641$

Comment: Of course, if the fundamental solution has $y > 1$, then none other can have prime $y$. D'oh. So we need only look at $D = n^2 + 1$. Anyhow, even though primes are quite rare also for $D = 17$, it looks like $D = 5$ is particularly prime-unfriendly. Thanks.

Comment: some nice references in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412079.pdf  which is not precisely on the topic; 2003 AMS book with one author van der Poorten. Anway, per an earlier comment, this sequence has $x_{n+2}  = 18 x_{n+1} - x_n$ and any or your $D$ will have a similar recurrence

Comment: Instead of $18,$   the coefficient for $D = n^2 + 1$ becomes $4n^2 + 2$

Comment: Solutions of $x^2-37y^2=-1$ with $y$ prime include $21169$, $29924555258984612689$, and $1984678229514310237244882392849$

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Let $\alpha = (2 + \sqrt{5})$ and $\beta = (2 - \sqrt{5})$. Note that $\alpha \beta = -1$. The general solution is given by

$$y_n = \frac{\alpha^n - \beta^n}{\alpha - \beta} = \frac{\alpha^n -\beta^n}{2 \sqrt{5}}$$

for $n$ odd. (This follows from general theory and I could explain it but I suspect that you know --- you can use induction, for example). This is related to the fact that $\alpha$ is a unit in the ring $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$. However, what is secretly going on is that there is the larger ring $\mathbf{Z}[\phi]$ where

$$\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2},$$

and in fact $\phi$ is the fundamental unit, and we have $\alpha = \phi^3$ and $\beta = -\phi^{-3}$. So

$$2 y_n =  \frac{\phi^{3n} - (-\phi)^{-3n}}{\sqrt{5}}$$

is actually divisible by

$$ \frac{\phi^{n} - (-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt{5}} = F_n,$$

where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number. (This divisibility takes place in $\mathbf{Z}[\phi]$, but the ratio $2y_n/F_n$ is a rational number which is an algebraic integer and thus an actual integer.) Hence $y_n$ is divisible by $F_n$ if $F_n$ is odd and by $F_n/2$ if $F_n$ is even (and the ratio is also $> 1$ for $n > 1$). This shows that $y_n$ is not prime as soon as $F_n >
 2$, so for $n > 3$. Hence $y_3 = 17$ is the only prime value.

For more general Pell-type equations I think one is generally out of luck unless there are forced divisibilities as in this case, and looks similar to the primality or otherwise of the sequence $2^n - 1$.

**Added:** I guess for those who want a more elementary solution, one can observe (and prove by induction) that the $y$ are given by

$$\frac{1}{2} F_{6n+3} = \frac{F_{2n+1} \cdot (5 F^2_{2n+1}  - 3)}{2}$$

and the RHS is easily seen to be prime only for $n = 1$ whence $F_9/2 = 34/2 = 17$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Great answer $(+1)$!

Comment: Similarly, we could show that solutions to $x^2-5y^2=+1$ are given by $y=\dfrac12 F_{6n}$, so $y$ is divisible by $\frac12 F_6=4$ (that could also be shown using modulo $4$ considerations on $x^2-5y^2=1$) and also  $\frac y4 $ is never prime, right?

Comment: It is a real pleasure to see a very satisfactory answer from a new contributor.

Answer (score 3):

The general solution of the negative Pell equation $\;x^2-5y^2=-1\;$ is the following

$\begin{cases}
x_n=\dfrac12\bigl[(2+\sqrt5)^{2n+1}+(2-\sqrt5)^{2n+1}\bigr]\\
y_n=\dfrac1{2\sqrt5}\bigl[(2+\sqrt5)^{2n+1}-(2-\sqrt5)^{2n+1}\bigr]
\end{cases}$

$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\;.$

Since

$\begin{align}
2+\sqrt5&=\dfrac{16+8\sqrt5}8=\dfrac{1+3\sqrt5+15+5\sqrt5}8=\\
&=\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^3\;,
\end{align}$

$\begin{align}
2-\sqrt5&=\dfrac{16-8\sqrt5}8=\dfrac{1-3\sqrt5+15-5\sqrt5}8=\\
&=\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^3\;,
\end{align}$

it follows that

$y_n=\dfrac1{2\sqrt5}\left[\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{6n+3}-\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^{6n+3}\right]$

$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\;.$

Let $\;F_n =\dfrac1{\sqrt5}\left[\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^n-\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^n\right]\;$

be the $\;n^{\text{th}}\;$ Fibonacci number, then it results that

$\begin{align}
y_n&=\dfrac1{2\sqrt5}\left[\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{6n+3}-\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^{6n+3}\right]=\\
&=\dfrac1{2\sqrt5}\left[\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{2n+1}-\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^{2n+1}\right]\cdot\\
&\quad\quad\cdot\left[\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}-1+\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}\right]=\\
&=\dfrac1{2\sqrt5}\left[\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{2n+1}-\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^{2n+1}\right]\cdot\\
&\quad\quad\cdot\left[\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}+2+\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^{4n+2}-3\right]=\\
&=\dfrac1{2\sqrt5}\left[\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{2n+1}-\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^{2n+1}\right]\cdot\\
&\quad\quad\cdot\left\{\left[\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^{2n+1}-\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^{2n+1}\right]^2-3\right\}=\\
&=\dfrac12 F_{2n+1}\biggl(5F_{2n+1}^2-3\biggr)\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}\;.
\end{align}$

Hence,

$y_n\;$ is prime $\iff F_{2n+1}=2\iff n=1\;.$

Moreover,

$y_1=\dfrac12 F_3\biggl(5F_3^2-3\biggr)=\dfrac12\cdot 2\biggl(5\cdot 2^2-3\biggr)=17\;.$